# How can I ensure a scope property is passed when using a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that requires some information to be passed in as scope properties, it's partially defined like this:

```
.directive('rangedInput', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                lower: "@",
                upper: "@",
                amount: '=ngModel'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
```

How can I ensure that `lower` and `upper` are passed in when this is consumed?

Comment: I think only way you can ensure is to place a validation for these.

Answer (score 1):

In your link function you can check for these attributes have value assigned and either log to console or throw error

```
if(!attr.lower || !attr.upper){
   throw "lower and upper attributes should have value";
}
```